# How to fix Pyarrow.dataset.dataset.take() spend so much time to featch the data

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyarrow

For my code, the idx of def **getitems**(self,idx) is a list, each element is random from 0-59999,the lenth of idx is 32. When I use sample = self.dataset.take(arrow_array) to fetch data, it will spend so much time.

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, pyarrow_dataset):
        self.record_count = 0
        self. batch_count = []
        for _ in pyarrow_dataset.to_batches():
            self.record_count += len(_)  
        self.dataset = pyarrow_dataset# Count the records in the current batch

    def __len__(self):
        return self.record_count

    def __getitems__(self, idx):
        # sample = self.dataset.to_batches().take([idx])  # Use to_batches to get the record
        self.comsume_time = 0
        
        
        arrow_array = pa.array(idx,type=pa.int64())
        start_time = time.time()
        # print(dataset.take(arrow_array).to_pandas())
        sample = self.dataset.take(arrow_array)  # Use to_batches to get the record
        end_time1 = time.time()

        # labels = sample['label'].to_pandas()
        labels = sample['label'].to_pandas()

        # image = torch.FloatTensor(sample['image'].to_pandas()).view((28,28)).unsqueeze(0)
        images = torch.FloatTensor(sample['image'].to_pandas()).view(32,1,28,28)
        
        comsume_time = (end_time1-start_time)
        with open('/home/yue21/mlndp/ML_example/result/take_time.txt', 'a') as take_time_save:
            take_time_save.write(f"take_operation_time: {comsume_time} second\n")
        # image = torch.tensor(sample[0]['image'][0])

        # batch_data = [{'data': images[i], 'target': int(labels[i])} for i in range(len(idx))]
        batch_data = [{'data': images[i], 'target': int(labels[i])} for i in range(len(idx))]


        return batch_data
```

I want to ask how to optimize this part?